# Scientific notation when importing data from MySQL to node.js by express

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

As in the title, I have very long ID's in my database, and when I import them to node.js by express, in object data is converted to scientific notation, and rounds after 16 places.

31551979034426737773395171961457358310  -->  3.1551979034426736e+37
59493556845631438533043909910482570895  -->  5.949355684563144e+37

value.toLocaleString('fullwide', {useGrouping:false}) = 31551979034426736000000000000000000000

Is there a way to keep the accuracy other than changing type in MySQL to text and then translating it to proper form? I don't see other way because when express receive data it's already rounded. Those are ID's so they need to be represented in accurate form and I don't really want to change all database just cause of js limitations.

Comment: Probably the easiest thing to do is import them as strings. You could try using BigInt values as an alternative (add "n" to the end of the numeric constants).

Comment: Note that the values are not "converted"; exponent notation is how the default presentation of large numbers is done in JavaScript. They're still ordinary JavaScript numbers (with, as you have noted, limited precision).